# ERROR: syntax error at or near "SETS"

Tags: postgresql

I'm getting a syntax error when trying to use the `GROUPING SETS` function in my Postgres DB.

I've looked at the documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS) and I believe the syntax is correct, but I'm still getting an error.

I believe the syntax should be `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((COLUMN), (COLUMN), ())` to get the grand total of my `SUM()` from the the `SELECT` part of my code. So I put in `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((amount.date), ( places.place), ());`

What am I doing wrong here?

```
SELECT 

  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM amount.date),
  places.place,
  CASE
      WHEN places.place = 'A' THEN SUM(amount.amount)
      WHEN places.place = 'B' THEN SUM(amount.amount)
      WHEN places.place = 'C' THEN SUM(amount.amount)
      ELSE SUM((amount.amount) * 2.5)
  END  AS "Total"

FROM amount

LEFT JOIN places                            ON places.id = amount.id

WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM amount.date) = 2017

GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((amount.date), (places.place), ());
```

Comment: What does `select version()` give you?

Comment: `PostgreSQL 9.4.11`

Comment: grouping sets was introduced in Postgres 9.5, [the manual for 9.4](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-table-expressions.html) does not show them. You should always use the manual that matches your Postgres verion

Comment: You're right. Thanks for pointing that out.